# How to avoid change detection in parent component being triggered by child component scroll event

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I am using a `BehaviorSubject` that acts as a state for a child component

```
state = new BehaviorSubject<any>({transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'});
styleState = this.state.asObservable();
```

In the child component template I subscribe to the state using the `async` pipe

```
<div>{{ styleState | async | json }}</div>
```

Then I update the child component state with the scroll event

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

    fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'scroll').pipe(
      tap((e: any) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.state.next({ scrollTop: e.target.scrollTop });
        });
      })
    ).subscribe();

  });
}
```

Now in Parent component, the change detection is being triggered by the child component scroll event

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  console.log('Parent View Checked!');
}
```

The problem is that the logic depends on the scroll event, and I don't want it to trigger a change detection in the parent component. knowing that I use `OnPush` change detection strategy in both parent and child component

Is this normal? how can I avoid it?

Here is a minimal reproduction https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkwvy4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: The link to the stackblitz is not valid.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I fixed it now!

Comment: This is how angular change detection working. Since angular is tree of components Whenever asynchronus process happen,
The change detection will triggered from app-root to bottom.

Comment: Check this:https://juristr.com/blog/2017/03/angular-tuning-change-detection/

Comment: @Chellappan Not sure, here the opposite is happening, parent would not console log `'Parent View Checked!'` if I didn't subscribe to the scroll event in the child

Comment: I have checked the stack blitz. If i did not subscribe the parent is not getting triggered

Comment: @Chellappan Yea!! that's what I am saying, It want to subscribe without triggering parent change detection

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but for anyone still looking for a solution:

**Why this is happening:**
Async pipes are special and *are* something the OnPush change detection strategy pays attention to. This article has a section specifically dedicated to the async pipe and contains a full explanation plus a lot of other relevant info: https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/

**Potential Alternative:**
There are a lot of ways you could do this, but here is one quick solution that accomplishes change detection for scroll inside a child component and does not trigger change detection in the parent.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3ubyo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts